# How to set EF context initialization through configuration file and seed when needed?

Tags: entity-framework, initialization, configuration-files, seeding

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 and would like to set the initialization through a configuration file. At the same time I would like run a seed method when the setting in the configuration file is one that that drop and (re)create the database.

Unless I am mistaken the `Seed`method will only be called when setting an initializer through code. Any way to specify what initializer to run in a configuration file (or whatever) in order to make the `Seed` method run when the configuration file species the database to be dropped and created?

If not, what other option is recommended?

Comment: define **when needed** ..

Comment: @YuliamChandra Clarified the question by editing it.

Comment: No, You are the one who needs to edit the question to clarify further. What do you mean by **when needed**, depends on some kind of parameter in the config or any other criteria you need to explain further..

Comment: @YuliamChandra As I said, I did clarify the question by editing it.

Comment: sorry I didn't see your changes, I just answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in the `DbContext` constructor as follow.

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext()
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Initializer"] == "DropAlways")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppContext>());
        }
        else if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Initializer"] == "DropIfModelChanges")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AppContext>());
        }
        else
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppContext>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yah, I suspected that was the way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @tschmit007, even if we put it outside the constructor, missconfigured setting will still drop the database, that's configuration fault not programming..

Comment: @tschmit007, I agree, that depends on OP now